# Process hangs if web browser crashes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium + python, been using implicit waits and try/except code on python to catch errors. However I have been noticing that if the browser crashes (let's say the user closes the browser during the program's executing), my python program will hang, and the timeouts of implicit wait seems to not work when this happens. The below process will just stay there forever.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import time
import sys
import os

def open_browser():
    print "Opening web page..."

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
    #driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    return driver


driver = open_browser() # Opens web browser

# LET'S SAY I CLOSE THE BROWSER RIGHT HERE! 
# IF I CLOSE THE PROCESS HERE, THE PROGRAM WILL HANG FOREVER
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    try:
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')
        break
   except:
        driver.quit()
        driver = open_browser()
```

Comment: seems like this is a bug when a socket connection is closed destructor should kill the driver.

Comment: It is 2019 and it still happens. Did you find a way to handle it in Python? In R-Selenium, I can sucessfully catch a browser crash and return to the page Selenium was.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided will always hang in the event that there is an exception getting the google home page.
What is probably happening is that attempting to get the google home page is resulting in an exception which would normally halt the program, but you are masking that out with the except clause.

Attempt with the following amendment to your loop.

```
max_attemtps = 10
attempts = 0
while attempts <= max_attempts:
    try:
        print "Retrieving google"
        driver.get('http://www.google.com')
        break
   except:
        print "Retrieving google failed"
        attempts += 1
```

Comment: Here is the thing. The code gets hung in the "try" section but it never reaches the except. So that means there is no exception thrown, but when the browser closes for a reason, and selenium looks for an element or tries opening a page, no exception is thrown and the code hangs.  I have edited the code on what I am doing on the except portion, it just never reaches it.